# How to activate registers in vim?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

So far if I installed vim-gtk on Ubuntu I could use the system clipboard register out of the box. After typing ["] that very symbol would appear in the bottom right part of vim.

https://askubuntu.com/a/434994/248437

Now (working on Linux Mint 17.3 which is based on Ubuntu 14.04) nothing happens after typing ["]. So my question is - do I need to activate Vim registers somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're telling Vim that you're about to do a command that references a register, but you're not telling Vim what the register is or what the command is.

In this case you want to "put" from the clipboard register, so you type this:

```
"+p
```

See:

```
:help "+
:help p
```